# Bind an attribute to an other existing attribute

Tags: xsd

i want to create a XSD.
One optional element in the XSD is `<PrintoutSettings OrderSource="NameOfOrder_X" .../>`

Another substructure of the XSD is

```
<Order Name="NameOfOrder">...</Order>
<Order Name="NameOfOrder2">...</Order>
...
```

My aim is it, that the attribute `NameOfOrder_X` of `<PrintoutSettings .../>` must be a string that was defined in one of the `<Order>...</Order>` - elements.

How can i realize it in a XSD?

Kind regards
sb

### ---

### ---

---

Here some of my XSD:

```
<xs:complexType name="Order">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="Documents" type="Documents"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Translator" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Proofreader" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="LockedBy" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:complexType name="Orders">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Order" type="Order"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="QQDBData">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Orders" type="Orders"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="LocalSettings" type="Settings"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute default="2000-01-01" name="CreationDate" type="xs:date" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="QQDBData" type="QQDBData">
    <xs:key name="PK-Orders">
        <xs:selector xpath="Order"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@Name"/>
    </xs:key>
    <xs:keyref name="FK-PrintoutSettings" refer="PK-Orders">
        <xs:selector xpath="PrintoutSettings"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@OrderSource"/>
    </xs:keyref>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: What is the multiplicity relationships between Orders and PrintoutSettings?  I'd bet that many Orders use one PrintoutSetting. @DevNull is on the right track with ID / IDREF, but the usage might need to be reversed depending on the relationship between the two ComplexTypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you've got from @DevNull is technically correct (+1); it is, however, not so much XSD; have a look at [this section](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#schemaConstraintsVsXML1) from the schema primer to understand the limitations you have with ID/IDREF.

I'll take the schema put forward by DevNull and modify it to show you the recommended XSD approach that relies on key/keyref.

UPDATE: I took your schema and updated to make sure it is sufficient for my tests:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:complexType name="Order">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="Documents" type="Documents"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="Translator" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="Proofreader" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="LockedBy" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Documents"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Orders">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Order" type="Order"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="QQDBData">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Orders" type="Orders"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="LocalSettings" type="Settings"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute default="2000-01-01" name="CreationDate" type="xs:date" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Settings">
        <xs:attribute name="OrderSource" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="QQDBData" type="QQDBData">
        <xs:key name="PK-Orders">
            <xs:selector xpath="Orders/Order"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@Name"/>
        </xs:key>
        <xs:keyref name="FK-PrintoutSettings" refer="PK-Orders">
            <xs:selector xpath="LocalSettings"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@OrderSource"/>
        </xs:keyref>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

What I had to do is to update the selectors, since by introducing additional tags, the XPath has changed. I always try to visualize the constraints, to ensure that the XPaths as described still make sense.

[image: Key-KeyRef]

An updated sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<QQDBData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" CreationDate="2000-01-01">
    <Orders>
        <Order Name="Name1" Translator="Translator1" Proofreader="Proofreader1" LockedBy="LockedBy1">
            <Documents/>
        </Order>
        <Order Name="Name1" Translator="Translator1" Proofreader="Proofreader1" LockedBy="LockedBy1">
            <Documents/>
        </Order>
    </Orders>
    <LocalSettings OrderSource="OrderSource1"/>
</QQDBData>
```

An error message, for the same invalid XML may look like (I am using QTAssistant to validate):

`Error occurred while loading [], line 12 position 3
The key sequence 'OrderSource1' in Keyref fails to refer to some key.`

Comment: I have a question. The Order-element is a complex type and have children which are complex types so i get an error with the xs:NMToken-Type for Order. What is here the right solution?

Comment: @Shounbourgh, Order doesn't need to be text (simpleContent); could be a complex type as well, it wouldn't change anything from the solution.

Comment: So i added some XSD code to my question. The problem, i get no error after validating my XML-Document. Maybe i forget something?

Comment: @Shounbourgh, please see the updated post; I had to fix the XPath used in the selectors; take a look at the diagram, and compare with your XSD, should be easy to see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an attribute type of `xs:ID` for `<Order>` and an attribute type of `xs:IDREF` for `<PrintoutSettings>`.

**Example XSD:**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="doc">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Order"/>
        <xs:element ref="PrintoutSettings"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Order">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:NMTOKEN">
          <xs:attribute name="Name" use="required" type="xs:ID"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="PrintoutSettings">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="OrderSource" use="required" type="xs:IDREF"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Example of INVALID XML:** (Gives the error "There is no ID/IDREF binding for IDREF 'NameOfOrder_X'." in Xerces.)

```
<doc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="book.xsd">
  <Order Name="NameOfOrder">...</Order>
  <Order Name="NameOfOrder2">...</Order>
  <PrintoutSettings OrderSource="NameOfOrder_X"/>
</doc>
```

**Example of VALID XML:**

```
<doc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="book.xsd">
  <Order Name="NameOfOrder">...</Order>
  <Order Name="NameOfOrder2">...</Order>
  <PrintoutSettings OrderSource="NameOfOrder2"/>
</doc>
```

Comment: Good job.  I wrote a clarification comment in question about multiplicity.